# Share GameObjects between scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

Let's assume I have a GameObject 'Player' and two scenes A and B.
If I add this GameObject 'Player' on both scenes and then make some changes (e.g. adding a script in Scene A), can I somehow achieve that the GameObject 'Player' stays the same in both A and B?
Or do I have to update the GameObject in both scenes manually?

I couldn't find a convenient way to achieve this.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [prefabs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html).

Comment: Why you would put this GameObjet into A and B instead of transfer the same from A to B when you change the scene? The most common approach thinking in player (your own example) is to create it at level 0 or some savepoint and persist it as singleton throught levels until it dies, so the question is "why you need to avoid this common approach and place 2 players that are the same think into each level?"

Comment: @rutter I'm looking for a way to share the gameobjects between scenes, not the scene itself. Can prefabs achieve that too?

Comment: @Frohlich How would you do that?

Comment: DontDestroyOnLoad() method tells Unity to persist a GameObject between scenes... You just need to declare it on one of your behaviour's Awake/Start state...

Comment: @Fabian Bigler I thought you may want to do something different than just persist object between scenes, that's why I ask before answer ;) If your concern is just about persistence between scenes so DontDestroyOnLoad() will solve it =)

Answer (score 5):

If you just need to persist GameObjects between scene transitions you can use [DontDestroyOnLoad()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) method.

Something like this should makes de deal:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MyPlayer : MonoBehaviour {
    void Awake() {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
    }

    // myPlayer behaviour....
}
```